# ROS nav stack with google cartographer pure localization

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I am new to this so please forgive if the question is silly. I am trying to integrate Google cartographer with the ros nav stack and doing a few sanity checks. The cartographer gives out heading angle in the format 0 to 180/-180. Is it possible to find out if the ros nav stack accepts heading data in the same format or in 0 to 360 format?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315031/ros-nav-stack-with-google-cartographer-pure-localization/) by [Manu14](https://answers.ros.org/users/39869/manu14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your best bet is to just test it! Localization is just setting the updated map -> odom frame transform when run so the actual location of the robot isnt all that important if you're just trying to replace AMCL.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-02-07**:
ROS represents rotations as quaternions (not euler angles), so there isn't any confusion about wrapping either.